# Android linphone building under Ubuntu 16.04 giving error of cmake path variable of CC and CXX?

Tags: c++, c, linux, android-ndk, linphone

I am trying to build linphone on linux Ubuntu 16.04 32 bit system. I have downloaded all the required libraries and install cmake. But i always ended with error as shown below.

> cmake /home/silvans/linphone_new/linphone-android/submodules/cmake-builder -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/home/silvans/linphone_new/linphone-android/liblinphone-sdk/android-arm64 -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/silvans/linphone_new/linphone-android/liblinphone-sdk/android-arm64 -DCMAKE_NO_SYSTEM_FROM_IMPORTED=YES -DLINPHONE_BUILDER_WORK_DIR=/home/silvans/linphone_new/linphone-android/WORK/android-arm64 -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=toolchains/toolchain-android-arm64.cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_MESSAGE=LAZY -DLINPHONE_BUILDER_CONFIG_FILE=configs/config-android.cmake -DLINPHONE_BUILDER_EXTERNAL_SOURCE_PATH=/home/silvans/linphone_new/linphone-android/submodules
>   -- Android: Selected Clang toolchain 'aarch64-linux-android-clang3.6' with GCC toolchain 'aarch64-linux-android-4.9'
>   -- The C compiler identification is unknown
>   -- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
>   CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
>     The CMAKE_C_COMPILER:
>
> /home/silvans/Downloads/android-ndk-r11c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/clang
>
> is not a full path to an existing compiler tool.
>
> Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
>     variable "CC" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_C_COMPILER to the full path to
>     the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.
>
> CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
>    The CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:
>
> /home/silvans/Downloads/android-ndk-r11c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/clang++
>
> is not a full path to an existing compiler tool.
>
> Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
>     variable "CXX" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to the full path
>     to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.
>
> -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
>   See also "/home/silvans/linphone_new/linphone-android/WORK/android-
>   arm64/cmake/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
>   See also "/home/silvans/linphone_new/linphone-android/WORK/android-arm64/cmake/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

As per error shown set the path for CC and CXX as below,

```
export CC=/usr/bin/gcc
export PATH=$PATH:$CC
export CXX=/usr/bin/g++
export PATH=$PATH:$CXX
```

But still i am getting the same error message. Please let me know what is wrong in the path variable of C and C++ compilers. How can i set them in the system so that cmake can find the path of both compilers.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Your compiler is not able to locate proper toolchain.
exporting it to `/usr/bin/gcc` is not correct solution, because i.e. gcc compiler for your native machine and if I'm right here you trying to cross compile.

Follow the link given below:
https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/111

Linphone wiki:
https://linphone.org/dokuwiki/doku.php/getting-started:android
See if it is helpful.